# Why did the leaves of my pepper plant become partly white after transplanting?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, plant-health, peppers

I am growing a scorpion pepper plant and I have an issue. Since transplanting,  all of the new growth is white. I used miracle gro potting mix. The seedling was previously in a pot with a different plant of which I don't know what is in the dirt.

The picture shows the plant. The half green leaf was already half formed when transplanted. The existing green stayed while the new part became white, which is why that leaf is partly green and partly white. It has been 2 weeks and it is continuing to grow new leaves that look healthy, but they're green and white. It is kept indoors.

Why would the leaves be growing white and green like this all of a sudden?

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is why this is happening all of the sudden.

Comment: Hi blindguy. I see you've been around the network, but this is your first time here, so welcome!  I re-worded your question a bit to try to make it more clear. If I've done something wrong, feel free to rollback! Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that miracle gro potting mix was a bit too strong on the fertiliser for such a small plant/seedling, it is more enriched than most general purpose potting composts. Give it more light and as it grows, this discoloration should resolve itself.

Comment: looks good @Sue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should gradually move this plant outdoors for more light.  Start by putting it in a shaded area and move to full sun over a period of a week.

It should green up (ie: produce more chlorophyll in the leaves) in response to higher light levels.

Comment: I will try putting it closer to the window some.  The only thing is that this was immediate after transplant so I am thinking there might be something different in the soils.

Comment: the window worked, I am still not sure why the white started when i transplanted it.  It was growing green fine before in the artificial light.